# Partial index creation takes the CPU down

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, cpu

I am trying to create an index on a table with a couple of million entries. Unfortunately, whenever I try it, the CPU goes up and I have to kill it around 90% CPU utilization, because otherwise it would harm production.

What can I do to create the index then? It's a partial index. I have already set `maintenance_work_mem` to 2GB. I can't really change `checkpoint_segments` while the database is running. `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` would take the database just down quicker.

So what else could I do?

Comment: You could set the database process to a lower process priority. You will get the same CPU load, but it will behave much nicer with regards to sharing. For that, you might need to start PostgreSQL manually from the command line and use `nice` with a fitting priority during the build.

Comment: What exactly is using that 90% CPU?

Answer (score 1):

Index creation certainly can't hit 90% CPU on a modern multicore system (mainly because it's using just one core). What's more likely you're blocking all the queries against the table. Please try building the index `CONCURRENTLY` ([manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html)).